# Movement of the elevator inside the building

Tags: java, object-oriented

The project is about simulation 5 elevators in 5-storey building. In the real world example, an elevator is going up then going down.

Example going up `1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5` then down `4 - 3 - 2 - 1` then up again `2 - 3 - 4 - 5`, etc.

The algorithm is simple; just two if blocks depend on the direction of the elevator. And if the elevator on the top floor breaks the loop and change direction to down. Also at the bottom floor do the same thing as well.

But obviously, there are code duplications and code smells.

This is works but I want to put a solid solution. How to improve this code?

Thanks in advance.

Elevator class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import static org.koucs.domain.FloorNumber.FOURTH;
import static org.koucs.domain.FloorNumber.GROUND;

@Slf4j
public class Elevator implements Runnable{

    private static final Integer MAX_CAPACITY = 10;

    private static final Integer WORK = 200;

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    private Direction direction;

    private Floor current;

    private final Building building;

    private final BlockingQueue<Person> people;

    private final String name;

    public Elevator(Building building, String name) {
        this.building = building;
        this.name = name;
        this.people = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(MAX_CAPACITY);
        this.direction = Direction.UP;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            isRunning = true;
            log.info("{}. elevator running.", name);
            while (isRunning) {

                if (direction.equals(Direction.UP)) {

                    log.debug("{}. elevator going up", name);

                    for (Floor floor : building.upFloors()) {
                        current = floor;


                        for ( Person person : people) {

                            if (person.getDestination() == current.getFloorNumber()) { // take people off

                                boolean drop = people.remove(person);
                                current.getPeople().put(person);

                            }
                        }

                        while (!current.getElevatorQueue().isEmpty()) { // take people in
                            if (people.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
                                break;
                            }
                            people.put(current.getElevatorQueue().take());
                        }

                        Thread.sleep(WORK);

                        if (current.getFloorNumber() == FOURTH) { // if elevator on the top floor
                            direction = Direction.DOWN;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (direction.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {

                    log.debug("{}. elevator going down", name);

                    for (Floor floor : building.downFloors()) { 
                        current = floor;
                        
                        for ( Person person : people) { 

                            if (person.getDestination() == current.getFloorNumber()) {
                                
                                boolean drop = people.remove(person);
                                current.getPeople().put(person);
                                
                            }

                        }
                        
                        while (!current.getElevatorQueue().isEmpty()) { 
                            if (people.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
                                break;
                            }
                            people.put(current.getElevatorQueue().take());
                        }

                        Thread.sleep(WORK);
                        if (current.getFloorNumber() == GROUND) {
                            direction = Direction.UP;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isRunning = false;
            log.error("", e);
        }

    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public Direction getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public Floor getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public BlockingQueue<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Building class

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Building {

    private Floor ground;
    private Floor first;
    private Floor second;
    private Floor third;
    private Floor fourth;

    private Elevator consist;

    private List<Elevator> elevators;

    private Elevator secondElevator;
    private Elevator thirdElevator;
    private Elevator fourthElevator;
    private Elevator fifthElevator;

    public Building() {
        ground = new Floor(FloorNumber.GROUND);
        first = new Floor(FloorNumber.FIRST);
        second = new Floor(FloorNumber.SECOND);
        third = new Floor(FloorNumber.THIRD);
        fourth = new Floor(FloorNumber.FOURTH);

        elevators = new ArrayList<>(4);

        consist = new Elevator(this, "1");
        secondElevator =  new Elevator(this, "2");
        thirdElevator =  new Elevator(this, "3");
        fourthElevator =  new Elevator(this, "4");
        fifthElevator =  new Elevator(this, "5");

        elevators.add(thirdElevator);
        elevators.add(secondElevator);
        elevators.add(fourthElevator);
        elevators.add(fifthElevator);

    }

    public Floor getFLoor( FloorNumber floorNumber ) {
        Floor floor;
        switch (floorNumber) {
            case GROUND:
                floor = getGround();
                break;
            case FIRST:
                floor = getFirst();
                break;
            case SECOND:
                floor = getSecond();
                break;
            case THIRD:
                floor = getThird();
                break;
            case FOURTH:
                floor = getFourth();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + floorNumber);
        }
        return floor;
    }
    
    public List<Floor> upFloors() {
        List<Floor> floors = Arrays.asList(ground, first, second, third, fourth);
        Collections.sort(floors);
        return floors;
    }
    
    public List<Floor> downFloors() {
        List<Floor> floors = Arrays.asList(ground, first, second, third, fourth);
        Collections.reverse(floors);
        return floors;
    }
}
```

Floor class

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

@Data
public class Floor implements Comparable<Floor>, Comparator<Floor> {

    private FloorNumber floorNumber;
    private BlockingQueue<Person> people;
    private BlockingQueue<Person> elevatorQueue;

    public Floor(FloorNumber floorNumber) {
        this.floorNumber = floorNumber;
        this.people =  new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        this.elevatorQueue =  new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Floor floor) {
        return Integer.compare(getElevatorQueue().size(), floor.getElevatorQueue().size());
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Floor o1, Floor o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getFloorNumber().num(), o2.getFloorNumber().num());
    }
}
```

Person class

```
public class Person {

    private final Integer id;
    private FloorNumber current;
    private FloorNumber destination;
    private final UUID uuid;

    public Person(FloorNumber current, FloorNumber destination) {
        this.id = 1;
        this.current = current;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public Person(){
        this.id = 1;
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public Integer get() {
        return id;
    }

    public FloorNumber getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(FloorNumber current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public FloorNumber getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(FloorNumber destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return uuid.equals(person.uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(uuid);
    }
}
```

FloorNumber enum

```
public enum FloorNumber {

    GROUND(0),
    FIRST(1),
    SECOND(2),
    THIRD(3),
    FOURTH(4);

    private final Integer num;

    private FloorNumber(Integer num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int num() {
        return this.num;
    }
}
```

Direction enum

```
public enum Direction {
    UP,
    DOWN;
}
```

Comment: You have external imports that I don't have in my IDE.  Can you modify your code so it's plain vanilla Java?

Comment: It would also be useful context if we could see `Building`, `Floor`, etc.

Comment: Just added other classes,